# how to pass and update variables between classes in C# ( variables that already store the data )?

Tags: c#, class, oop, tcp, modbus

I'm writing a modbus tcp program, so I have:

1. a class which stores variables
2. a class to process the received values
3. a class to send the processed received values through the ethernet

received value saved in required properties and everything is fine but when I use this saved value in that class which sends the data through the ethernet the value that is passed to the sending function, is zero

for example consider the function code (a variable that shown in the below picture) that stores the 7th received byte

[this is how I created the Function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjvDc.png)

[this is how I'm saving the 7th received byte in function code property (Modbus_Variable.Function_Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8viOw.png)

[this is the value that store in Modbus_Variable.Function_Code property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJnbA.png)

as you can see when I use function code in other classes (here I'm using it at a function to send the data over the ethernet) the value is zero
[monitoring value with debugging mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGrZs.png)

what is the solution to use the stored variables or properties all over my projects?

right now as you can see in below picture I'm creating a function to pass the values between classes
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdzWc.png)

and I'm looking for a better solution to use this variable all over my project

in case that you need codes:
in Modbupol namespace, Function_Code variable has been created to store the data

```
public class Modbus_Variables
{

    public byte Function_Code { get; set; }
}
```

in other class and namespace I'm saving some received byte from the ethernet inside of the variable and in the  public void Assing_Values_To_Addresses(byte[] Data_To_Send) function I'm using this variable:

```
public class Modbus
{
    Modbus_Variables ModBus_Variable = new Modbus_Variables();

    public void Store_Recieved_Bytes(byte[] Recieved_Bytes)
    {
        ModBus_Variable.Function_Code = Recieved_Bytes[7];
    }
    public void Assing_Values_To_Addresses(byte[] Data_To_Send)
    {

       Data_To_Send[7] = ModBus_Variable.Function_Code;

    }
```

in socket_server namespace I'm using a function to send data through the ethernet:
but as I said Modbus_Variable.Function_Code returns zero

```
public class Server_Socket
{
  
  Modbus_Variables ModBus_Variable = new Modbus_Variables();
    private async void TakeCareOfTCPClient(TcpClient paramClient)
    {
await stream.WriteAsync(Data_Of_Header_File, ModBus_Variable.Function_Code , 11);

    }

}
```

Comment: pleasde don't post images of code. Instead copy the code directly as text into your post, so others can copy it in order to try the code out.

Comment: Is your shared data some kind of configuration? What is its purpose? If you can describe what these variables-class should actually *do*, you probably can solve the issue yourself. Try to describe the architecture of your app: what objects does it consist of and how do those relate to one another. Usually there's no such thing as "global variables" in a truely OOP-design. However there are objects that depend on others.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain hey there
thanks for your feedback but the codes are not usable because there are lots of libraries and classes  and for a better understanding of what is happening in debug mode i attached pictures

Comment: If you already know how to use the debugger, then continue to debug! If a property has the incorrect value, where is it set? does the code reach that place? The implied question of "what is a good architecture for my program?" is a bit to broad, especially since it is really not very clear what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Community hey there
thanks for your feedback but the codes are not usable because there are lots of libraries and classes and for a better understanding of what is happening in debug mode i attached pictures
u can not use the code because I'm sending one part of it. but u can understand the functionality of my code based on pictures. btw i'm asking for a concept. i don't want to solve my codes problem

Comment: we don't need your entire code, just the relevant parts (e.g. just the classes and some dummy-code for their functions) of it to reproduce your issue. Currently it's nearly impossible to understand your structure, as we literally can't see it nor copy it and try it out.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to post a good question here. There are tips about how to get that "relavant code" as well.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain ok as you need i imported some codes .... i hope that help

Comment: it's very hard to read your post, though, as it misses any punctuation. I'm scratching my head about what "throw the ethernet" might mean.

Comment: Aaaah, you mean "through", not "throw".